# Only PNG supports transparency, is that true?

Tags: image, image-processing, png, jpeg, transparency

I found JPG does not support transparency, the alpha value is always 255. I am wondering only png supports transparency?

Comment: There is a bunch of formats supporting transparency, just JPEG isn't one of 'em...

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-12.html

Comment: TGA targa i think has alpha channel. pic formats and bit depths are amazing complex. rgba argb in all combinations for 16 to 32 bit

Answer (score 84, accepted):

- `png-32` supports different levels of transparency. Each pixel can have an opacity between 0 and 255, with 0 as completely transparent.
- `png-24` supports setting one color as fully transparent. Everything else will be opaque.
- `gif` uses a color palette. You can specify that one color in the palette is fully transparent.
- `png-8` also uses a color palette but each color in the palette has its own opacity value, so it supports varying levels of transparency too.
- `jpg` does not support transparency.

Comment: This is not correct. Paletted PNG-8 supports varying levels of transparency (see [pngquant](http://pngquant.org)). *Only Photoshop and GIMP don't*, so you need better tools for this (e.g. Fireworks or the aforementioned pngquant).

Comment: And what about bitmap images?

Comment: PNG-24 supports only GIF-like transparency (one color is specified to be the transparent color and it is fully transparent).  PNG-32 supports different levels of transparency via the alpha channel, in which each pixel can have an opacity between 0 and 255.  There may be some applications that erroneously refer to PNG32 files as "PNG-24".

Answer (score 13):

JPEG 2000 supports full transparency.  See [JPEG 2000 Side channel spatial information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000#Side_channel_spatial_information).

Comment: JPEG2000 is a new file format, not an extension of the original JPEG format.

Comment: Not to be confused with the .JPG file format discussed in the question. JPEG 2000 is .jp2

Answer (score 7):

[JPEG XR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/wic/jpeg-xr-codec) (not the same as JPEG 2000) also supports transparency.
However it is not a useful format for the web as only Internet Explorer and Edge support it.

[WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) is another emerging image format with support for transparency.
However, Internet Explorer lacks support for it.

Answer (score 0):

From [Transparency (graphic) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(graphic)):

> Raster file formats that support transparency include **GIF, PNG, BMP, TIFF, TGA** and **JPEG 2000**, through either a transparent color or an alpha channel.