# Make background transparent using writeJPEG

Tags: r

Imagine I have an image called img.jpeg and I want to make half of it transparent.

I tried, without success, the code below:

```
library(jpeg)
img <- readJPEG("img.jpeg")
img[1:100, ] <- NA  # all the NA pixels should be transparent
writeJPEG(img, "img_1.jpeg", bg = "transparent")
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the `.jpeg` format does not support transparency.

So I would try using another format like `.png`, `.tif` or others.

You may have a a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147883/only-png-supports-transparency-is-that-true) post.

Comment: And what about writePNG, how would I set the transparent background?